# destroying gameObject in both cases in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have written a code where when the player is not being rendered in camera it should be destroyed but it is being destroyed even being rendered in camera, please see my below code;

```
using UnityEngine;

public class IfnotvisibleDestroy : MonoBehaviour
{
    public SpriteRenderer re;
   
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    public void Update()

    {
       
        if (re.isVisible)
        {
            Debug.Log(re.isVisible);
        }
        if(!re.isVisible)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the log and destroy happens in the same frame for the same instance of this component and renderer? What happens if you rather do `private void Update(){ Debug.Log(re.isVisible); if(!re.isVisible){ Destroy(re.gameObject);} }`? So log every state and destroy the object attached to the renderer not this gameObject

Comment: Try using FixedUpdate()

Comment: @NathanielCutajar what difference should that make?

Comment: @derHugo I'm thinking maybe it's a syncing issue between objects, where if it's fixed, it would be done in conjunction. Might be wrong tho

Comment: no problem guys i replaced the code with OnBecomeVisible() and OnBecomeInvisible() also :-D pls upvote this post as i have no repuatation yet.

Answer (score -1):

Do the destroy gameObject part inside the FixedUpdate function